# Can I install windows 7 on a USB Harddisk?

Tags: windows-7, usb, external-hard-drive

I need to install windows 7 (or windows server 2008 r2) on a USB harddisk, is it possible ?

I want to be able to select a partition on the USB drive as a possible location for installation (or something similar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no issues, as long as Windows setup can find the drive.

It is possible, however that  you may get this error:

[image]

To get around that, you will have to follow the steps [HERE](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7-to-usb-external-hard-drive-must-read/) to get around this error.

> The procedure is simple but you need to install Windows Automated
>   Installation Kit first to get some files.

The basic outline is that you download the [Windows Automated Installation Kit from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=696dd665-9f76-4177-a811-39c26d3b3b34&displaylang=en), open Installer.cmd from your system folder, and choose the drive you want to install on. Read the link for complete instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can not fully boot from a external USB drive. You can boot the installer but not completely boot. Sorry. If you want to boot the installer I'd look into [this](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool).